# How to reduce the axis text size in 3D bar plot in R?

Tags: r

```
              library(latticeExtra)

             cloud(Count ~ ParentOrganization + Star, dataset, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='#009689', xbase=.4, ybase=.5, cex.axis=0.00001, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1),
  par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")), distance=1, zoom=.9)
```

I have used this code and produced the given graph [image: 3D bar graph]

However, now I want to reduce the text size of the X-axis. How can I do this?